# Goal Line Technology in football

Tags: football, technology

Why isn't Goal Line Technology implemented? Are there any reasons why this technology is not being used in football?

Rugby has had a system to make the game fair for ages, but football hasn't yet implemented a similar system?

Comment: I once seen an interview with Platini where he explained why he didn't think it was a good idea to implement it in football because of the cost and logistics. I'll try find that interview

Comment: You should consider rewording the first half of your question because it sounds like you asking for people's opinion, I think the question is good though.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially it hasn't been introduced by UEFA because the top brass don't support it because of the financial cost. [Platini](http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/football/21970741) says:

> "I prefer to put more money into youth football and infrastructure than spend it on technology when there's a goal in a blue moon that hasn't been seen by a referee." 
>   "It would cost around 54 million euros (£46m) over five years for this technology, so it's quite expensive for the sort of mistake which happens once every 40 years," he said.
>   "In the Champions League, I'm very happy with the results (of a five-man team). Practically no mistakes have been made and the referees see practically everything that happens on the pitch."

That interview was from around 2013, I believe he is [open](http://www1.skysports.com/football/news/11095/9055555/michel-platini-open-to-goal-line-technology-at-euro-2016) to the idea of it being used at Euro 2016. FIFA seem to have the seem view of the issue. Some pundits and ex-footballers believe it would also slow down the flow of the game but the main reason for it not being implemented seems to be financial and logistical. I would guess that we will say goal line technology being used in only major tournaments such as the World Cup and major leagues like the English Premier League where the technology is currently being used.

Here is an interesting article on [Fifa's](http://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2014/mar/26/andre-marriner-referee-fifa-video-technology) attitude towards it.

Answer (score 1):

Platini has said:"I'm totally against the goal-line technology and let us appreciate the humanized football game continually. I insist on my point due to this is not only a problem of technology. What frightens me is that goal-line technology is able to be the beginning of football technicalization "

As a confrontational sport, football contains protean situations in confrontation.So the rules is impossible to be rigorous completely.The game need scales which are not need to remain consistency in the different games, but just need both sides in a same game not to violate the rules. Therefore, so far, the refereeing work is done by humans completely. It is only referees can choose and maintain a certain scale according to the different situations in the football games.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/23629154 to help Ciaran out. It has been used effectively in the Premier League all season and a cost of £250k to install seems well within the reach of top tier European clubs

Comment: I think Platini is referring to the cost of maintaining and installing this for every ground in the top flight leagues in football, I would imagine it would cost a lot but it should really be used for major competitions

Comment: Completely agree RoB - every top flight club with the revenue they generate should be able to afford it. I think it's a stretch too far for any club below Europe's top leagues though.

Comment: I would like to see it tried at tournaments like the World Cup or Champions League which have a higher profile and more revenue behind them before it would be introduced for a full season in a league. I can't even think of more than a couple of occasions where a ref has used it in England or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I think that is the point - it shouldn't come into play but should be there in the rare event that there is a dispute over whether the ball has crossed the line or not.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it; the costs of technology isn't the big issue. Rather, the problem lies in the very definition of what football is. I haven't got any quotes to lean on, but the fundamental idea of football is that "it's a 90 minute constant flow of events". Thus, having any sort of break in the game (exept for injuries and substitutions, of course) would be in violation to the fundamentals, and therefor unacceptable. Some goalline technology may pass this test, but should it come more technology to the sport, it would change it completely - and not in a positive manner!

Answer (score 0):

The English Premier League have brought goal line technology in for the first time this season. All referees have a special watch that gives them a signal if the ball has crossed the line.

Comment: Why don't you throw in a few references?