# Referee's mistakes in football/soccer

Tags: football, officiating

Please somebody explain, why can't referee just wait a few seconds, and look at the at the telebim, and then decide if it was a foul, or if ball crossed the goal line. It would solve many issues.

Comment: It would also dramatically increase the length of the game.

Comment: I don't think so. In the time after whistle players are trying to convince referee and discuss with him. it takes preety long time. If referee would decide after waching the replays, discussion with him would be pointless.

Comment: I think it's because not every league can afford that kind of technology.

Comment: I answered a similar question to this http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4309/goal-line-technology-in-football/4310#4310

Answer (score 3):

Short version answer: Because is not in the rules.

Long version answer: It can be implemented, but if you look at [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4309/477) question answers, you could see that there are other important aspect of the game that could be improved..

The 4th referee (or the 6th in a 5 referee game) could watch and decide, but it would involve several changes in the rules, like stopping time, give power to another officer to make the call, and what to do in that situation.